# How can I update a dataframe by reference?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a CSV file, which loaded into a dataframe (python/pandas). The original dataframe is `df_origen`, each row has a measure called `value` that was taken into an interval of 1 hour.

I need to "resize" each row into 4 rows in a new dataframe by periods of 15 minutes. It is possible has to have jumps in the data `df_origen`.

I did it.

```
df_destiny = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start, periods=96 * diff.days, freq='15Min'), columns=['from_time'])
```

After, I iterated the dataset `df_origen` to take the value into the field "value"  but I filtered by rows the dataset `df_destiny`:

```
tmp = df_destiny[df_destiny['date'] == row['date'] & df_destiny['to_time'] < row['to_time'] + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

when I modified the rows into the variable `tmp`, I noticed that I am update into a copy.

Is there someway to do this by reference?

I mean, can I modify the dataset `tmp` and see that changes into the dataset `df`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the `index` as new column

```
df_destiny['id'] = df_destiny .index
```

so when I filter the rows:

```
test = df_destiny[df_destiny['date'] == row['date'] & df_destiny['to_time'] < row['to_time'] + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)]
```

I have into the dataframe `test` the original index of the dataframe `df_destiny`. Then I can update

```
df_destiny.loc[test.iloc[0]['id'], 'value'] = int(value/4)
```

I don't know if there is another way ...